# Python VS Excel SUM calculation is different?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, numpy, decimal

I have an issue while trying to SUM the amount value in the files, their result seems inaccurate, for instance:

this is my code to SUM the amount of a file

```
from decimal import Decimal
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv_directory = r'D:\Work Documents\Apps\ACF PAS & MANUAL\DMS\Test\ACF_ID_DMSCM_01_20210131_0001.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csv_directory)
#df['TransactionAmount'] = df['TransactionAmount'].apply(Decimal)
#df['TransactionAmount'] = df['TransactionAmount'].astype('Float64') 
df['TransactionAmount'] = df['TransactionAmount'].astype(np.float64)
#total_amount = df['TransactionAmount'].sum()
total_amount = np.sum(df['TransactionAmount'])
print(total_amount)
```

there is many commented line code, indicates that I tried many method, the result of my code is:
-5.960464477539063e-08

when I manually SUM it using Excel, the result is
-1.26432860270143E-06

I tried another file and the results is:
Python: 0.0330020189285278
Excel: 0.0330020906404

there is a slight difference but it makes an inaccurate statement, I want the results is as same as Excel, how should I do ?

Comment: Could you add some sample data to the question that could help to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Both your results in the first set are close to the limit of precision for Float64 and for Excel; if you got there by adding even smaller numbers you are bound to loose precision.

Comment: Check [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). Excel precision is limited to 15 digits. I'm pretty sure Python can handle more precision and that would explain the differences

Comment: For small floating point differences like this, use `np.isclose()` for comparison instead of the various implementations of exact equality.  Asking two computers/programs/threads the answer to a floating-point math problem will very often give you two slightly different results.